# Two raid controllers in one HP ML350 G4 server

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, hardware-raid

Here's the situation: I have running HP Proliant ML 350 G4 server, which already has Adaptec AAC-RAID controller and 2 HDD built as Raid-1. Now, I want to add another 2 HDD but for them I have another controller (FastTrak TX2200). I connected the controller to the PCI slot and wired new HDDs. Then using FastTrak raid controller menu I created a new Raid and it shows me as one logical disk. However, my Ubuntu OS, does not recognize it as one drive - it shows me them both as different drives! I haven't partitioned the new drives yet, so maybe that might be the problem?

Comment: I'm curious. Where did the HP Smart Array RAID controllers go? That's usually the best choice for ProLiant servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This controller is so-called "[driver-based RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Firmware.2Fdriver-based_RAID)" and need a special driver. It seems that Ubuntu has not those drivers. Follow [this](http://firstweb.promise.com/marketing/datasheet/file/FTTX2200_DS_021405.pdf) sheet TX2200 have support in RedHat and SLES. You can compile your own version from [source code](http://firstweb.promise.com/support/file/Driver/1_ft%20tx2300%20and%20tx2200%20linux%20kernel%202.6%20psc%20v2.6.0.0331.tgz)

Notes from FastTrak:

> This Linux source code should only be used by experienced Linux users.
>   This code is designed to be used with Linux kernel 2.6. This code is
>   provided as-is and Promise Technology does not provide technical
>   support for the code.

Comment: The colloquial term for the FastTrak crap is "fake-raid" and you'll find plenty of people lamenting the problems encountered when using it. I *strongly* recommend against subjecting yourself to such aberrations; use a good hardware RAID HBA or full software RAID.